# Post to Instagram by opening Instagram app – iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, instagram-api

I have an Instagram scheduling app and I am trying to open this (see image below) in Swift 5.x. The goal is simple: save Image to Firebase, once it is time to post, notification!, user clicks on the notification and this (image below) opens up with the appropriate image/video to post. Everything works except for opening Instagram with the appropriate photo/video. I have tried this:

```
    func postToInstagram(image: URL) {
        let videoFileUrl: URL = image
        var localId: String?
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: videoFileUrl)
            localId = request?.placeholderForCreatedAsset?.localIdentifier
        }, completionHandler: { success, error in
            // completion handler is called on an arbitrary thread
            // but since you (most likely) will perform some UI stuff
            // you better move everything to the main thread.
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard error == nil else {
                    // handle error
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                guard let localId = localId else {
                    // highly unlikely that it'll be nil,
                    // but you should handle this error just in case
                    return
                }

                let url = URL(string: "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=\(localId)")!
                guard UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else {
                    // handle this error
                    return
                }
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        })
    }
```

and this:

```
    func postToInstagram(image: URL, igURL: String) {
        let urlStr: String = "instagram://app"
        let url = URL(string: igURL)
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!) {
            print("can open")
                UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
```

To no avail. The latter code works, but only opens the Instagram app itself, which is fine, but I would like to open the View in the image below rather than Instagram's home screen. I also tried changing the URL to "instagram://share" and this works but goes to publish a regular post, whereas I want the user to decide what they want to do with their image.

This is where I want to go:
[image: Post to Instagram]

Note: For everyone who will be telling me this and whoever will wonder: Yes, my URL schemes (LSApplicationQueriesSchemes) are fine. And, just to clarify, I need to fetch the image/video from Firebase before posting it.

Comment: did you update `Info.plist` with `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`

Comment: Yes! This is what I meant by URL schemes

Comment: iF I'm not wrong, you might have to use Instagram Graph API with the permission "instagram_content_publish"